# What is the simplest way to accept and reroute payments in Flutter

Tags: flutter, payment-gateway, payment-processing, google-pay

I'm building a Flutter application and in it I'd like to accept user payments and programmatically route the payment through to a "merchant's" bank account.

For example if an item, call it I, is listed in the app from Merchant X and User A decides to purchase item I, then I'd like for the app to accept payment from User A and pay the necessary amount directly into Merchant X's bank account.

What would be the simplest plugin (or payment processor/gateway) for Flutter I could use to achieve this functionality?

I looked into Google Pay for Flutter, but I think that plugin only handles the use case when Merchant X and the app developer are the same entity in my example above (if I'm wrong please correct me). I looked into Stripe for Flutter as well, however Stripe is not available in the country I'm based in, so I cannot use it.